# "Show next page button when" and multiple choices reported in next question

Tags: cognito-forms

I am currently trying to edit a form in Cognito Forms, and there are two functionalities I can't configure properly:

**1. "Show next page button WHEN" condition**

I have a multiple choice question with checkboxes. The field is required. Visitors must choose four answers exactly. I would like to let visitors see the "Next page" button ***when and only when*** they have checked exactly four choices. I've tried everything I could (which is obviously not enough!) with the Advanced Editor and common yes/no calculations. I did not succeed.

What do you think is the best formula for this condition?

**2. How to report multiple choice answers in next question (in Rating Scale)**

Now, I want the previous four required choices, chosen by the visitor, to be reported in the rating scale on the next page.

Can I do that - and how?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can set up a 'When' condition on your Page Break to show only when your Choice field set to Checkboxes has 4 items selected. In my fallowing example my Choice field will have the label 'Choice Field'. I set up this calculation in the advanced editor for the 'When' condition on the Page Break.

```
=(ChoiceField.Count() = 4)
```

As for the second part of your question. We can't take the value that has been selected in the Choice field, the options, and add them to the Question section of a Rating Scale.